# Parse multiple JSON entries using org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParser

Tags: spring-boot

I'd like to parse a JSON Array using the native JsonParser available in Spring Boot:

```
String url="https://restservice.com";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String resp = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

JsonParser springParser = JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
Map<String, Object> map = springParser.parseMap(resp);
```

That works if there's just one item in the Array. If multiple items are returned, an exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParseException: Cannot parse JSON
    at org.springframework.boot.json.AbstractJsonParser.tryParse(AbstractJsonParser.java:60) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.json.JacksonJsonParser.parseMap(JacksonJsonParser.java:55) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.samplewebapp.DemoApplication.lambda$demo$2(DemoApplication.java:50) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token
```

What is the correct API to return a List of Map JSON objects?

Comment: Have you tried `parseList`?

Comment: Can you show an example of what the data you're trying to parse looks like?

Comment: This means your data is an array. `Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token` It would be easier to help you if you could provide the input and the expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Showing the JSON you are trying to parse would be helpful for getting a good answer to your problem.

Anyway, if you are trying to get a list you should use the `parseList()` method instead. This required doing a cast from objects to maps, but worked fine for me otherwise. Here's a quick example:

```
String json = "[{\"key\":\"value1\"}, {\"key\":\"value2\"}]";
JsonParser springParser = JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
List<Object> list = springParser.parseList(json);

for(Object o : list) {
    if(o instanceof Map) {
        Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>) o;
        //do processing here
    }
}
```

However, I would suggest calling the desired parser (Jackson, gson, etc.) directly if you need more control over the process. Jackson provides a handy `ObjectMapper` class to help with this sort of thing and avoid messy type conversions.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem! Keep in mind that the "native JsonParser" that Spring Boot uses is just the first parser it finds in your classpath [as seen here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/json/JsonParserFactory.html#getJsonParser--). So, it's probably still worth checking out these other libraries so you can get a feel for how to use them later on when this simple parse method isn't enough.